# How to parse bluetooth raw data

Tags: java, bluetooth

I am getting a Bluetooth device raw data from my gateway and want to parse it to extract some information but it is not showing properly. Actually, the device manufacturer shared a document where it mentioned that battery level info can be found at offset 13 with a length of 1 but understand how to decode this byte to get battery level. Here is my code with the parse method which hardcoded raw data as a string(0201060303AAFE0C16AAFE10E8016D696E657700):

```
   public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] b = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            b[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character
                    .digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return b;
    }
    
    
   private void parse() {
        String s = "0201060303AAFE0C16AAFE10E8016D696E657700";
        byte[] adv = hexStringToByteArray(s);

        if ((0x03 & adv[4]) == 0x03) {
            System.out.println("info frame");
           System.out.println("battery:" + new String(new byte[] {advData[13]}));

        }
    }
```

Here is the device manufacturer document:
[image]

Comment: What is the data showing as?

Comment: You should check the doc for type of "battery level" but its probably not a string, certainly an int. side note: to parse hex: `HexFormat.of().parseHex(s)`

Comment: Have no information except this document. Is there any other way to convert Hex to plain text instead of using HexFormat?

Comment: What is the difficulty? In the dummy data *0201060303AAFE0C16AAFE10E8016D696E657700* the battery level (offset 13) is 1% (0x01)

Comment: @g00se: can you please share the code how you find offset(13) value:1%(0x01)?

Comment: I'm talking about your own hardcoded data

Comment: I know but how you get this value?

Comment: That's the value that appears at offset 13: *0201060303AAFE0C16AAFE10E8**01**6D696E657700*

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are trying to decode the wrong BLE advertisement. Decoding your example creates the following data.

The raw data: 02 01 06 03 03 AA FE 0C 16 AA FE 10 E8 01 6D 69 6E 65 77 00

leads to the following BLE Advertising Data Types:

| Raw data | Bluetooth LE Advertising Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| 02 01 06 | Flags |
| 03 03 AA FE | Complete List of 16­bit Service Class UUIDs 0xFEAA (Google LLC, Eddystone Protocol) |
| 0C 16 AA FE 10 E8 01 6D 69 6E 65 77 00 | Service Data ­16­bit UUID 0xFEAA, Eddystone Protocol |

Decoding the Eddystone data, see [1]:

| Raw data | Eddystone frame encoding |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | URL |
| E8 | TX Power: -24 dBm |
| 01 | URL Scheme Prefix: https://www. |
| 6D 69 6E 65 77 00 | Eddystone-URL HTTP URL encoding: minew.com/ |

resulting URL: https://www.minew.com/

[1] https://github.com/google/eddystone/blob/master/protocol-specification.md

Comment: you might be right as i have seen that offset(4 and 13) are same in case of device info and eddyston url frame which device is advertising. I am not fully understand your conversion here, can you please share the example code which you use to decode this raw data?

Comment: I have dissected your raw data according to the [Bluetooth specifications](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/). I didn't use any software and it's not really difficult to do this by hand.

Comment: And one more little thing, the UUID 0xFFE1 is not an official [assigned number](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Assigned-Numbers-2022-12-12.pdf). This looks a little fishy to me

Comment: Right, actually there are different frames that I am receiving and there are many formats so far I can see that have confusion to filter out only interesting data. I wish to have some library in java to do that. Please hint at that if you know anyone in your experience.

Comment: I always write my own software and have therefore never needed a programme library. Unfortunately, I can't give you any tips for your search.